# MSSQL query for multiple table where no connection between them

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, join

Need help for SQL SERVER Query

I have five tables, `Roles`, `Requirements`, `Documents`, `RoleRequirments`(. `role` has many `requirements`), `RequirmentsDocuments` (`requirements` has many `documents`).

And now I need `Role document` report there is not the direct connection between them but I am trying via `requirement` table.

I need all documents along with roles id.

```
doc-id label roleids
 1      A       2,5,6
 2      B       2,1
 3      C       5 

SELECT d.title, d.id as doc_id, m.moduleId as mid , d.type,m.label, STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(rc.roleid AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()] FROM edoc_link_role_req as rc WHERE rc.reqid= cd.reqid FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') as roleid FROM edoc_link_role_req rc 
LEFT JOIN edoc_link_req_document cd ON cd.reqid = rc.reqid
LEFT JOIN edoc_document d ON cd.documentid = d.id 
WHERE d.installationid = 1
```

Comment: I only count 4 tables?

Comment: In query, i am using only three,

Comment: You need `Roles LEFT JOIN  RoleRequirments LEFT JOIN RequirmentsDocuments LEFT JOIN Documents` (pseudocode).  Then you can reach the document via connected tables

Comment: Then why mention that you have 5 tables and then state 4 if you're only using 3 in this query?

Comment: I am able to reach documents but I need comma separated roles id for each document

Comment: Do `LEFT JOIN edoc_document d ON cd.documentid = d.id 
AND d.installationid = 1` to get true left join behavior. (When in WHERE, you get regular inner join result...)

Comment: @new_php_developer check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server Getting comma-separated ids isn't trivial in SQL server

Answer (score 0):

Is it the equivalent of MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT you're after, i.e. join together roleids for each docid?

If so, see:
[Simulating group_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server)